# Xcode wants to access DeviceManager in your keychain and tells me to add Spotify to Accessibility

Tags: xcode, keychain, spotify

Every now and again (when I plug my iPhone into my Mac with Xcode open), I get the following dialog:

[image]

The only problem is when I click 'Allow' or 'Allways allow', it pops up with this:

[image]

Should I trust this? Why does Spotify needto be in accsessability when Xcode needs to accsess 'com.apple.dt.XcodeDeviceMonitor' in my keychain? What should I do about it?

Comment: To take a screenshot of a window, after ⇧⌘4, press space, then click on a window (or ⌥-click to screenshot without shadow).

Comment: @grgarside I didnt think that worked with popup alerts.